# implementation of graphs in python that have a label

Tags: python, graph-theory

Inspired by the https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/ information in this link, I have been implementing graph structures. I generally use the

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
             'B': ['C', 'D'],
             'C': ['D'],
             'D': ['C']}

edges = [('A','B',20),('A','C',40), ('B','C',10), ('B','D',15),('C','D',10),('D','C',10)]
```

These two are the closest I can get to object representation in C. But sometimes I have to store more information about the graph labels. For example, the graph nodes are states within a country, so  I have to store the full name (california) and abbreviation (CA) along with each node.
What is the best way to do it. I know dictionary values can be class instances, but not dictionary keys. So I was just thinking of creating a separate dictionary with  the graph node 'A' as key and class instance 'StateDetails' as the value which contains the state and abbreivation. For example

```
state_map = {'A': StateDetails('California','CA') ..    }
```

I would appreciate if someone tells me a more efficient way to deal with this problem in particular and with graphs in general in python

Comment: Have you looked for a library?

Comment: I wanted to implement these things on my own because I was preparing for google interviews and trying to implement data structures in python. So use of library for that is a no no

Comment: In that case, you might like to look into implementing your own classes to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your class as a dict key if you implement `__eq__` and `__hash__`, for example:

```
class StateDetails(object):
    def __init__(self, state, abbrev):
        self.state = state
        self.abbrev = abbrev
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.abbrev == other.abbrev
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.abbrev)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({!r}, {!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.state, self.abbrev)

CA = StateDetails('California', 'CA')
AZ = StateDetails('Arizona', 'AZ')
NV = StateDetails('Nevada', 'NV')
UT = StateDetails('Utah', 'UT')
graph = {CA: [AZ, NV],
         AZ: [CA, NV, UT],
         NV: [CA, AZ, UT],
         UT: [AZ, NV]}
```

Result:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(graph)
{StateDetails('California', 'CA'): [StateDetails('Arizona', 'AZ'),
                                    StateDetails('Nevada', 'NV')],
 StateDetails('Arizona', 'AZ'): [StateDetails('California', 'CA'),
                                 StateDetails('Nevada', 'NV'),
                                 StateDetails('Utah', 'UT')],
 StateDetails('Nevada', 'NV'): [StateDetails('California', 'CA'),
                                StateDetails('Arizona', 'AZ'),
                                StateDetails('Utah', 'UT')],
 StateDetails('Utah', 'UT'): [StateDetails('Arizona', 'AZ'),
                              StateDetails('Nevada', 'NV')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the extra info outside your graph. E.g. keep a dict

```
full_name = {"CA": California,
             # 49 more entries
            }
```

then use `"CA"` as the graph node.

This makes the graph algorithms must easier to implement because you don't have to work around the extra information that the nodes are dragging along, it makes them maintainable because the information you're storing might change, and it might also make them faster.

(In fact, for a real-world application I'd use integer indices only as the graph nodes and store all the extra information in a separate structure. That way, you can use NumPy and SciPy to do the heavy lifting.)

Answer (score 0):

How about storing data in the standard JSON format?

```
state_map = { "A": { "state_name": "California", "state_code": "CA" } }
```

To find the state name of `A`, now just type

```
state_map['A']['state_name'] # California
```